# How to use underscoreJS to sort a collection based on certain attribute value?

Tags: sorting, collections, underscore.js

I have a collection of objects and I want to be able to sort it in such a way that all objects with certain attribute value as 'false' should appear before the others. This is the structure of the collection

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
attribute1: some value
attribute2: some value
attribute3: some value
attribute4: false
```

I want all objects with attribute 4 value as false to appear before those with attribute4 value as true. How can this avhieved with underscore?

Answer (score 1):

Convert `attribute4` to a number and sort by that...

```
var sorted = _(unsorted).sortBy(function(x) { return x.attribute4 === false ? 0 : 1; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split the array into two pieces based on `attribute4` then you're not really sorting, you're partitioning. If so then you can use [`_.partition`](http://underscorejs.org/#partition) to pull the array apart and [`_.flatten`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) to put the parts back together:

```
var a = [
    { p1:  6, p2: false },
    { p1: 11, p2: true  },
    { p1: 23, p2: true  },
    { p1: 42, p2: false }
];
var b = _(a).chain()
            .partition(function(o) { return !o.p2 })
            .flatten()
            .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EWd35/

If you really are sorting, then you'll almost certainly want a secondary sort key and then you should use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) instead of Underscore's `sortBy` (which doesn't handle multi-key sorts at all well):

```
var b = a.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.p2 == b.p2)
        return a.p1 - b.p1;
    if(a.p2)
        return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kLMeB/